# How can i make a cardview dropdown hover effect that includes icons in the menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a cardview dropdown hover effect that when i hover on Services button it gives me options with text and icons next to them: like these[how hover menu are suppose to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFG6H.png). But i haven't been getting the desired look. I've trid so many ways but it's still not working. Now when i hover on it, oit just gives me normal options and it's not even the desired cardview look. Can you please review my codes and help me where you can

here are my codes:

```js
// Text to be typed in a typing animation
const textLines = [
    "Accurate and timely data that guides their decisions",
    "Increased crop yield and quality",
    "Reduced use of fertilizers and pesticides",
    "Improved resilience to weather and other external factors",
    "Enhanced data-driven decision-making",
    "Empowering farmers to make informed choices about their crops"
];

const typingText = document.getElementById("typing-text");
let textIndex = 0;
let charIndex = 0;
let isDeleting = false;

// Function to simulate a typing animation
function typeText() {
    const currentLine = textLines[textIndex];
    if (!isDeleting) {
        typingText.textContent += currentLine.charAt(charIndex);
        charIndex++;
        if (charIndex >= currentLine.length) {
            isDeleting = true;
            setTimeout(() => typeText(), 1000);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => typeText(), 50);
        }
    } else {
        typingText.textContent = currentLine.substring(0, charIndex);
        charIndex--;
        if (charIndex < 0) {
            isDeleting = false;
            textIndex = (textIndex + 1) % textLines.length; // Loop through textLines
            setTimeout(() => typeText(), 500);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => typeText(), 50);
        }
    }
}

// Start the typing animation
typeText();

// JavaScript for handling the hover effect for the "Services" text button

// Select the "Services" text button and the service dropdown
const servicesButton = document.querySelector(".nav-button");
const serviceDropdown = document.querySelector(".service-dropdown");

// Add an event listener for when the mouse enters the "Services" text button
servicesButton.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    serviceDropdown.style.display = "block";
});

// Add an event listener for when the mouse leaves the "Services" text button
servicesButton.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    serviceDropdown.style.display = "none";
});

// Add an event listener for when the mouse enters the service dropdown
serviceDropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    serviceDropdown.style.display = "block";
});

// Add an event listener for when the mouse leaves the service dropdown
serviceDropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    serviceDropdown.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
/* Basic styling for the header (unchanged) */
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333; /* Adjust background color as needed */
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* Rearrange the button positions (unchanged) */
.user-actions {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between buttons */
    flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Reverse the button order */
}

.rounded-button {
    background-color: #007bff; /* Button background color */
    color: #fff; /* Button text color */
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px; /* Rounded edges */
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add styles for the button container (unchanged) */
.button-container {
    text-align: center; /* Center the button horizontally */
    margin-top: 20px; /* Add space between the content and the button */
}

/* Footer styles */
footer {
    text-align: center; /* Center the text horizontally */
    background-color: #333; /* Footer background color */
    color: #fff; /* Text color */
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* Rest of your existing CSS styles remain the same */


/* Add styles for the content container */
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 20px; /* Add space around the content */
}

/* Add styles for the text on the left */
.text {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px; /* Add space inside the text container */
}

.text h1 {
    font-size: 24px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text p {
    font-size: 16px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Add styles for the right image */
.right-image {
    width: 50%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    margin-top: 20px; /* Add space below the header */
    margin-right: 40px; /* Increase the margin to move it further to the right */
}

/* Rest of your existing CSS styles remain the same */

.right-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

/* Rest of your existing CSS styles remain the same */
/* Add styles for the services dropdown */
.services-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-button {
    cursor: pointer; /* Add cursor pointer for the "Services" text button */
}

.service-dropdown {
    display: none; /* Set initial display to "none" */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: left;
}

/* Show the dropdown when hovering over the "Services" text button */
.nav-button:hover + .service-dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.service-dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.service-dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Agrisense360</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="images\bckgrd.jpg" alt="Agrisense360 Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="services-container">
                <div class="nav-button">Services</div>
                <div class="service-dropdown">
                    <div class="service-option" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                        <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <h4>Electronic Sensor Installation and Setup</h4>
                            <p>Provide farmers with the hardware and expertise needed to install electronic sensors
                                in their fields.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="service-option" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                        <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <h4>Data Analytics and Insights</h4>
                            <p>Provide farmers with recommendations based on the data collected, such as when to
                                irrigate, when to apply fertilizers, and when to take pest control measures.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-option" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <h4>Real-Time Monitoring and Data Collection</h4>
                            <p>Subscription-based service where farmers can access real-time data from the sensors
                                installed in their fields.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-option" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <h4>Crop Management Consulting</h4>
                            <p>Personalized consulting services to farmers based on the data and insights gathered
                                from their fields.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-option" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <h4>Integration with Farm Equipment</h4>
                            <p>Partnerships with agricultural equipment manufacturers to integrate your technology.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-option" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <h4>Customized Reports</h4>
                            <p>Customized reports for farmers that summarize the performance of their crops over
                                time.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <a href="#" class="nav-button">About Us</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-button">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div class="user-actions">
            <button class="rounded-button" id="login">Log In</button>
            <button class="rounded-button" id="register">Register</button>
        </div>

    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="text">
            </p>
            <h3>Agrisense360,</h3>
            <p>Optimizing Crop Yield with Electronic Sensors,<br>
                Ushering in an era of data-driven decision-making.</p><br>

            <p>Giving our farmers the tools, they need to make choices
                rooted in information and foresight:</p><br>

            <p id="typing-text"></p><br>
        </div>

        <div class="right-image">
            <img src="images\sensorview1.webp" alt="Large Image">

        </div>
    </div>


    <button id="get-in-touch">Get in touch with us</button>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 Agrisense360. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you're not coming far with `path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`. Thats not the real url, you'll need to purchase a licence for fontawesome or use a free old resource of them.

Second: in your provided example is not a single CSS rule for the contents inside that Service Navigation item. That won't style itself..